# Data not persisting into database

Tags: c#, sql-server

There is no error showing and when I press insert the "Record Saved Successfully" message shows but the data is not showing in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Paytoll_Management_System
{
    class DBConnection
    {
        public SqlConnection con;
        public SqlCommand cmd;
        public SqlDataAdapter sda;
        public string pkk;

        public void Connection()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Integrated Security=True;"); //datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=payrolldb
            con.Open();
        }

        public void DataSend(string SQL)
        {
            try
            {
                Connection();
                SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trans.Commit();
                pkk = "";
            }
            catch
            {
                pkk = "Connection Failed!";
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        public void DataGet(string SQL)
        {
            try
            {
                Connection();
                sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, con);
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

insert statement

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Validation())
        {
            if (IfUsernameExists(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                con.DataSend("INSERT INTO [Users] (name, email, username, password, role, dob, address) VALUES('" + txtName.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "','" + txtUsername.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + cbRole.Text + "','" + dtDob.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + "','" + txtAddress.Text + "')");
                MessageBox.Show("Record Saved Succesfully!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Clear_Data();
                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does your insert statement looks like?

Comment: If the database is attached to the server do not use the local database.  Instead for the Data Source us the server name and instance shown on the login window of SQL Server Management Studio.  The localDb is a MDF file that is not attached to the server.

Comment: There are many things wrong here. You are passing in sql and executing it. That is a MAJOR problem. You need to use parameterized queries. You also are not handling connections properly. They need to be closed and disposed immediately after use. You also have an anti-pattern here I call try/squelch. That is where you use a try catch block and swallow the error and pretend it didn't happen.

Comment: can you show us the database logs?

Comment: thank you. i will try that.

Comment: And storing passwords in clear text is borderline criminal. Passwords need to be salted and hashed. The reason you get back the message that everything worked is because in your DataSend method you swallow the error and pretend nothing went wrong and your code merrily continues along its way despite something previous that failed. I would start by removing every single one of those try/catch blocks. Then learn how to parameterize your queries. Finally run this is debug and find the issues.

Comment: Place 'MessageBox.Show("Some Error has occured!")' instead of 'pkk = "Connection Failed!";'

Comment: You are not catching the exception in the `DataSend` method.  if you catch the exception, then you can see what went wrong.  instead of this `pkk = "Connection Failed!";`

Comment: Honestly I would probably start over. I notice you have sql code in a button click event. You want a separation of layers. You don't have a data layer here which you need. Your button click would call the method in your data layer. Honestly that Connection class you have is causing you a lot of grief because you open a connection in one method and never close it at all. The connection and command objects should be in a single method wrapped up nice and clean inside a USING statement.

Comment: "there is no error showing" because you swallow just about all of them. Never have a catch exception in code. There are two articles on Exception handling that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET | You are also keeping the DbConnections and other disposeable stuff around. Create. Use. Dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using block. That is my rule Nr. 1 for Disposeables.

Comment: i used the code Sean Lange provided below but it seems there is something wrong with my connection string, An System.NullReferenceException is thrown. how can i resolve this? here is my connection string :@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: Change the catch part of Try-Catch into `catch (exception e)  { MessageBox.Show(e.Message);}` and you'll see what's going wrong, then you can ask for help on the error.

Comment: Message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much cleaner way to deal with the logic. It will handle exceptions,  database connections and the query is parameterized. All three of these are major problems in the code you posted. I would prefer to see a data layer instead of logic directly in a button click event but that isn't crucial to this working correctly. I would not even use that DBConnection class you have. There are just way too many holes in that to be salvageable without a LOT of work.

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (Validation())
        {
            if (IfUsernameExists(txtUsername.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username already exists!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO[Users](name, email, username, password, role, dob, address) VALUES(@Name, @Email, @username, @password, @role, @dob, @address)";
                    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtName.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtEmail.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUsername.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtPassword.Text; //This really needs to be salted and hashed instead of plain text!!!!
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@role", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = cbRole.Text;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dtDob.Value;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtAddress.Text;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Record Saved Succesfully!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                Clear_Data();
                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Log the error here so you have a record of it.
        //Maybe even send an email that something failed
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "An error occurred.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Since you don't have the connection in the config file (although you should), you would use this for your connection.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PC-67\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Integrated Security=True;"))
```

Comment: thank you! im very new to c# and your advices are greatly appreciated. i will try to absorb all the things you said and hopefully become much less of an embarrasment in the future :D

Comment: Don't feel embarrassed. We were all knew to every language at one point or another. I apologize if I made you feel that way. Hopefully this will help you see a better way of dealing with these things.

Comment: I hope so too :D it seems that my connection string is incorrect because the try catch block is throwing an System.NullReferenceException, how can i resolve this?
Here is my connection string: @"Data Source=PC-67\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Integrated Security=True;"

Comment: If you are talking about in the code I posted it is because my code is looking for the connection string in the connection strings section of the config file. I should have mentioned that. You don't want your connection string in your code. The config file is a nice central location that can be accessed from anywhere. I would suggest doing that. But in the meantime just switch that out with your connection string.

Comment: using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"Data Source=PC-67\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PayrollDB;Integrated Security=True;"].ConnectionString))
 is this right?

Comment: No that is a mismatch of using the config file and a hard coded string. See my updated answer.